# body onlload not being fired with IE 10

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, onload

I've got a very simple page (I'm testing handling the tab key in textareas) where I want a function called when the body loads.

After finding that the onkeypress function was not being called, I put an alert in the onload function, as the first line:

```
window.alert("onload");
```

I get the alert output with Chrome and FF, but not with IE 10.There are no errors in the IE debugging console.

I've used onload many, many times before - where is my mistake?

It has been a long day, what am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="allowtab.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="createTextareaKeyPressFunction(5);"> 
<textarea cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

******************** Below is a n Edit ******************
Here are the first three lines of the .js file:

```
function createTextareaKeyPressFunction(insertChar) {
window.alert("onload function");
window.console.log("onload");
```

I added the window.console.log call and it did not cause any output in the console.

IE is not reporting that it is block any popup with the alert.

All of this works properly with FF and Chrome.

Get the alert output, the entry in the log, and my code works.
********************** Another EDIT *******************

I stripped the .js file to:

```
function createTextareaKeyPressFunction(insertChar) {
window.alert("onload function");
window.console.log("onload");

}
```

and the HTML to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="allowtabstripped.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="createTextareaKeyPressFunction(5);"> <!-- execute the createTextareaKeyPressFunction function when the page has loaded -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

FF and Chrome execute alert and log call and display the alert text and the entry in the console, IE does neither.

It has to be something basic that I'm just not seeing!!!!!

I am loading the web page via the file system, and to be safe I just add a "Mark of the Web" line

```
<!-- saved from url=(0009)http://localhost/ -->
```

IE still does not execute the alert or the log call - or my code if I test the full version of the HTML and JavaScript with the mark of the web.

Comment: Use console.log, not alert. Is pop up blocker blocking the alert?

Comment: Can we see the content of `allowtab.js` ?

Comment: Could you explain better what you are trying to do? Maybe give a jsfiddle URL? It might sound like you are trying to set ways to handle tab keys on all textareas after the page is loaded but this is just me jumping to conclusions.

Comment: body onload works fine. May be issue is with allowtab.js or createTextareaKeyPressFunction

Comment: I've updated my post to the first three lines of the .js file containing the function being specified with onload=

Comment: If you must know, I'm dynamically building onkeypress event handlers for all the textarea on the page. The function will catch the tab key press, cancel the default action by: theEvent.preventDefault ? theEvent.preventDefault() : (theEvent.returnValue = false);  and then inserting either a tab control character \t or a string of characters the user specifies when codiing the body onload function, or, if they pass an integer, I will insert that many blanks.

Comment: Accidently pressed Enter while making that last comment and the edit time expired as I I was trimming what I wanted to post down to a size the bloody forum software would allow.  The comment I meant to post follows this one:

Comment: If you must know, I'm dynamically building onkeypress event handlers for all the TAs on the page. The function will catch the tab press, cancel the default action by: theEvent.preventDefault ? theEvent.preventDefault() : (theEvent.returnValue = false);  and then inserting either a tab control character \t or a string, or several blanks, based upon the argue passed to the onload function. My example shows that 5 blanks will be inserted I can do it differently but I want to nail down what I'm doing wrong here. I use onload all the time and it  works. I do not like to leave things unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved -

As I said in my last edit to the my original post, I was loading the HTML file, in the browser, via the file system - file:///

I also say that I tried putting a "mark of the web" with no change to the behavior.

I have WAMP installed for local testing and I just created a virtual host, via WAMP, for the directory with this HTML and JavaScript, that is not working in IE, and loaded through the virtual host.

It works.

The onload function is being fired but my code to handle the tab key is not working, I'll do a bit of debugging... Found it, a simple typo.

I now have a function which you can hang on the keydown event of a  that will allow you to actually use the tab key to edit the text in the  - it does not take you to the next element on the web  page as is the default behavior of the tab key on a web page.

Yes, I know that it changing the default behavior, but I'll warn users about it.

I think I will change the way the event handler is created and invoke it "hang" it on the event via the keydown= parameter on the  tag itself.

I realized while playing with the code - that I can have the tab key (or any key for that matter) insert anything I want inserted at the insert point - I think I will be able to use that when I have to make major changes to things - like add prefix code to several lines the lines don't begin the same and a global find/replace won't work.

Sort of a configurable text editor - no, I won't go wild and wind up created yet another online editing function :-) There are plenty of those sort of "wheels" that work well and another is not needed.

Anyway, I know have a way to allow the use of the tab key for formatting in a .

I'll go clean it up and make sure the comments (one per line of code) or correct.

Now, why do I think I've used onload before, with the "page" being loading through the file system and it works with IE - maybe prior to IE 10??????

I'll have to ponder that one.

Just another demonstration of the chaotic state of "standards" on the web - and in the PC world in general.

I post the cleaned up code somewhere, I have a site a bobnovell.com that I've not done anything to in a while - I'm not exactly proud of it :-)

But I'll put up a page www.bobnovell.com/tabintextarea.shmtl by late Saturday - it is currently Thursday, June 16, 2016 at 1804 CDT - showing the code and how to invoke it.

Comment: That page with the code and examples is now up at http://www.bobnovell.com/tabintextarea.shtml